# c# regular expression only numerical characters in string

Tags: c#, regex, textbox, numerical

I want to check if a string with an undefined length consist of only numbers. Example:

```
"234324" = true
"er32" = false
"1" = true
```

the way I tried to solve this problem is like this:

```
public bool Validate(string input)
{
    return (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$")) ? true : false;
}
```

now im not a big hero with regular expressions, but according to everything I could find on the internet either the expression `"^\+$"` or `"^[0-9]$"` would work, but it doesnt :(

Comment: Does your input contain a newline of some sort? This, and `$` not matching on it would be the only reason why you code does _not_ work to my eyes.

Comment: Are you getting false positive or false negatives? Also pet peeve, but `condition ? true : false` is equivalent to `condition`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need for a `RegEx`here, you can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to check if a `string` is a valid integer.

```
public bool Validate(string input)
{
     int myNumber;
     return int.TryParse(input, out myNumber);
}
```

Note that `IsMatch`already returns a `bool`, `? true : false` is useless.

Comment: Only if the number fits in an int.

Comment: This is not regex. but question is regex. and your answer is not true when i have very large string

Answer (score 3):

```
int number;
return int.TryParse(input, out number);
```

Answer (score 3):

use `"^[0-9]+$"` insead of `"^[0-9]$"` (notice the + character) which means that multiple characters will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

`^\d+$` should work and does work for me. Your two examples at the end won't work because `^\+$` is missing the `d` (I assume this is a typo, but it should be `^\d+$`) and the second one needs a plus after the closing square bracket (i.e. `^[0-9]+$`).

I would check to see if trimming the input makes a difference, you might have whitespace that is causing problems. Otherwise your error is somewhere else and not in this code.

Answer (score 2):

If the string really can be of arbitrary length, then Ray is right in saying that the code in the accepted answer will fail if the number represented by the string is > Int32.MaxValue.

The following example will return false instead of true:

```
bool isNumber = Validate(Int64.MaxValue.ToString()); // isNumber == false
```

Here is an alternative solution that works for strings of arbitrary length:

```
public bool Validate(string input)
{
   return input.ToCharArray().All(c => Char.IsDigit(c));    
}
```